# MS AJAX Library 4.0 Sys.create.dataView

Tags: ajax

One again Microsoft poor documentation has left me confused. I am trying to use the new features of the .NET 4.0 framework. I am using the following code to populate the Title and Director but it keeps getting blank.

The service returns the result correctly like

`[d: { title = "ss, director ="" }` something like that but the li never gets populated.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

        Sys.require([Sys.components.dataView, Sys.components.dataContext,Sys.scripts.WebServices], function () {

            Sys.create.dataView("#moviesView",
    {
        dataProvider: "MovieService.svc",
        fetchOperation: "GetMovies",
        autoFetch: true          


    });

        });

</script>
```

And here it the HTML code:

```
 <ul id="moviesView">

    <li>
    {{Title}} - {{Director}}
    </li>

    </ul>
```

IS THIS THE LATEST URL TO Start.js file.

```
<script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/beta/0911/Start.js"></script>
```

Here is the Ajax-Enabled WCF Service:

```
 [ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class MovieService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        public Movie GetMovies()
        {
            return new Movie() { Title = "SS", Director = "SSSSS" }; 
        }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class Movie
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Director { get; set; } 
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the sys-template class attribute to the unordered list tag.

```
<ul id="moviesView" class="sys-template">
```

Here's an excerpt from [Client-side Data Binding in ASP.NET AJAX 4.0](http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/whitepapers/ClientDataBindingAjax4.aspx)

> The one other requirement for defining
>   a template is the parent element must
>   have the sys-template CSS class
>   applied, and that class must be
>   defined with display set to none, as
>   shown in the example above. This
>   convention serves two purposes – it
>   helps the parser identify which
>   elements are part of a template on
>   your page (which will become important
>   when we use declarative
>   instantiation), and it keeps the
>   template markup hidden until ASP.NET
>   Ajax has completed the binding (it
>   will toggle the display to be
>   visible).

Comment: thanks! that was it! I wonder why the ms ajax framework just cannot use the id of the control like moviesView and forget about the sys-template class. This seems a little more work.